# Expandable, standard TeX only way to compare balanced token lists

Tags: tex-core, expansion, token-lists

Is there a (reasonably) efficient macro that does something similar to
 `\long\def\comparets#1#2{\def\aa{#1}\def\bb{#2}\ifx\aa\bb true\else false\fi}`
except is expandable (i.e. `\newcomparets{<tokens1>}{<tokens2>}` would expand into either 'true' or 'false', including inside `\edef`)? I am looking for a 'pure' TeX (i.e. no extensions, such as e-TeX) solution. I have looked at `l3tl` macros but they seem to use e-TeX. The solution should work with arbitrary token sequences (including ones containing various flavors of 'funny spaces' and braces and arbitrary control sequences). I cannot seem to find a way to do this without performing several passes.

Comment: May we ask why no e-TeX?

Comment: No e-TeX, no (efficient, if any) expandable comparison

Comment: I prefer to stick to standard TeX for my macro packages, and have never needed e-TeX or any other extensions (although I have occasionally used extensions for 'one-off' jobs and even wrote my own, of which I am not very proud). I have a way to do this in TeX although it involves several 'parsing' passes but is 'prefix' expandable (with, say, `\romannumeral` trick). I just wonder if anyone has a clever way to do this.

Comment: @alexsh I'll be intrigued to see your self-answer here: one reason the LaTeX3 team decided to require e-TeX + `\pdfstrcmp` (or equivalent) is that there was no other way to reliably do such a comparison, at least that we could find.

Comment: e-tex is different to other extensions such as luatex or xetex in that (in all the major distributions), the binary is e-tex and "tex" is just e-tex running in compatibility mode with the extended commands disabled)

Comment: Do you really have a solution? I would be surprised that it is possible, if you step through token by token using `#1` parsing you lose spaces and `{}` groups and if you step through using `\futurelet` it isn't expandable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure you are right about `tex`: my understanding is that is still just Knuth's TeX (in contrast to `etex`, `pdftex`, `latex`, `pdflatex`, all of which use the pdfTeX engine)

Comment: I do. Let me clean it up (I did not expect anyone to be interested) and post it. I use the first pass to collect info on spaces and braces (using \string and \meaning), then use a combination of `#1` parsing and `\ifcat`, `\ifx` tests on tokens that are known to be 'consumable' (i.e. non blanks) and `\def\eatspace#1 {}` to consume 'real' spaces. The first step is the nasty one, since one has to keep track of the 'tail' of the sequence in every step.

Comment: @JosephWright yes true.

Comment: @alexsh: what you are asking for is impossible, as there is no expandable way of distinguishing the normal-catcode `&` from the active token `&` after the definitions `\catcode126=13\let~=&\catcode38=13\let&=~` (in other words, after the active `&` is let to an implicit `&`).  This of course is not specific to `&`.  The same problem arises after `\let\X=X \escapechar=-1`: `\X` and `X` are not distinguishable expandably.

Comment: @alexsh may I ask for what purpose aiming at such generality? I guess there must be some reason why a `\compare` assuming in particular all space tokens are standard doesn't fit the bill?

Comment: @jfbu: I repeat, the "active `&` let to `&`" and the "standard `&`" are indistinguishable through any expandable means, including `\ifcat`, `\meaning`, and `\string`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch sorry about that you are right. I delete my erroneous comment.

Comment: I see this is becoming more and more of a theoretical exercise. Ok, as far as  `\ifcat` et al are concerned, Bruno is right (see p. 209 of The Book, look for ..., unless...). But this is standard TeX we are talking about. It is quite easy to create a macro that lists all 255 of `\catcode` 13 characters (same with single letter control sequences) and does simple delimited parameter matching. My goal is to have something that works reasonably for most cases and cannot be thwarted by the crazy ones.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch my comment with `\ifcat` was wrong indeed, however (everywhere here `&` is the standard one): `\def\gobtotab #1&{}`
`\def\TEST #1{\gobtotab #1\POSITIVE &\NEGATIVE}`
`\def\POSITIVE &\NEGATIVE {YES}`
`\def\NEGATIVE {NO}` will successfully distinguish expandably  the "active `&` let to `&`" and the "standard `&`"

Comment: @alexsh and you want to allow *all* "crazy ones"? is there any reason if not theoretical for that?

Comment: @jbfu: as I mention above, you can create a single macro that does it by using _all_ characters as a single delimiter and then uses some 'creative' substitution. One sequence per character (you will need one for each single letter control sequence, as well, in view of the `\escapechar`dilemma) works faster but is less compact. Generality helps when doing debugging or writing `quick and dirty' prototype.

Comment: @jbfu: this has a bit of a philosophical bend but I noticed that the code that handles 'boundary' cases reliably is usually better designed. I may become an e-TeX convert (nah:)). I wish they had not abandoned the WEB source though.

Comment: @alexsh I had missed your earlier comment about delimited macros. I see your point about having a debugging swiss knife, but why not debug with `e-TeX` even if the final code is not `e-TeX` dependent?

Comment: @alexsh The e-TeX source is still a `.ch` file against `tex.web`: http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/etexdir/etex.ch?view=co. Perhaps you are thinking of LuaTeX? (pdfTeX and XeTeX use stand-alone `.web` files nowadays.)

Comment: @JosephWright I thought pdfTeX and LuaTeX merged. I have nothing againts extensions per se, I just miss Knuth's depth. On the subject of character vs cs test, some light relief: (assuming \batchmode=1) `\def\test#1#2\end{\show#1} \def\a{not a character} \expandafter\test\csname a &\endcsname\end`. A joke, of course (since `\batchmode=1` is not expandable think of it as a precondition along with `255>\escapechar>0`) :).

Comment: See also: [expansion - Define an expandable function for comparing a token list to a string in LaTeX3 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227592/define-an-expandable-function-for-comparing-a-token-list-to-a-string-in-latex3)

Answer (score 6):

I am unsure if posting this as an answer to my own question is kosher since it does not really answer it
but I will not flag it as such (even assuming I could) so if anyone has a flash of inspiration that solves
the original problem, I will gladly label it as a true answer.

Now about the macros. I apologize in advance for the shape they are in. They have been pulled (and re-re-renamed) from a variety
of code I have written over the years, so the style is a bit ... eclectic, shall we say. A lot can be optimized below but 
the problem of multiple passes remains as I will explain later, so if anyone has a clever trick to solve it,
please let me know.

There are a couple of caveats:

1) The actual comparison
 macros are missing, only the analysis part is present, which delivers, in 'prefix expandable'
way (e.g. works with the `\romannumeral-1` trick) a string of category 11 and 12 tokens that contains enough information
to identify every token in the sequence as far as its category, character code, if any, whether it is a brace,
its character code, etc. Such strings can be compared directly if desired.

2) Well, 1) is a white lie on two counts:

a) any token that can be grabbed as a parameter (i. e. a non space, non brace) is (grabbed and) just replaced by its `\meaning`
     string enclosed in t ... e (both t and e are category 11); note that category 10 tokens with character code other than
     32 fall into this category (pun intended). `\yygrabtokenraw` can be adjusted to provide better analysis 
     (a must if the goal is to compare arbitrary balanced lists of tokens but just boils down to a few carefully
      written conditionals). Note that just `\string` is not enough, either, since `\escapechar` can be -1.

b) the 'top level' recursion step is missing; the main problem here are braces of character code 32; they are dealt with
     in the very last stage when the length of the sequence is known and one can just `\string` every one of them up or find 
     out their `\meaning`. Well, not so fast because if they have category code 32, both `\meaning` and `\string` turn them into 
     ordinary spaces (the `\meaning` will end in two spaces which does not help either) which is one problem `\detokenize` 
     was invented to correct. Thus we need to decide how to grab them.
     The one guarantee the code makes is that every opening brace will be correctly identified as either character code 
     32 (`o1e` or `c1e`) or character code other than 32 (`o2e`, `c2e`). The code that does this messes up some of the closing braces that follow
     (their character codes) in order to safely consume the brace so `c2e` 'markers' following the first one are unreliable (however, if another `o1e`, `o1e` or `o2e` 
     is found, it is a brace of character code 32). The next iteration can grab the braces that are 
     'deciphered' without messing up the next brace.
     After many more passes (up to as many as there are closing braces, unfortunately), everything can be resolved. If anyone is interested,
     I can finish the macros to do this. Only if Knuth ended each `\meaning` with a dot ...

3)  The code spends a lot of time 'propagating expansion'. A typical situation is
    `\somemacro{<long list of benign tokens>}{\string}`; `\string` here needs to be expanded before anything else
    can happen, so `\somemacro` spends a lot of time inserting `\expandafter`s in the the `<long list ...>`. Note that
    the `\romannumeral` will fail if the `<long list ...>` is very long so coding everything as digits will not help.
    Using `\csname <long ...>\endcsname` is possible (with an `\expandafter` follow up) but I am uneasy about polluting
    TeX's hash table in this case.

The macros try to identify 'funny spaces' in the first pass, this is the only use for `\meaning` and `\yymatchblankspace` 
below. One can do with `\string` only.

A test case for the macro is included at the end. If I overlooked something 
stupid, my apologies (when Joseph Wright and others are suspicious, I tend to be too).

**EDIT:** On top of whatever else might be off with these, I omitted `\long` in front of every definition for clarity, so a `\par` will wreck it.

To expand on *provide better analysis* above: to resolve pathological cases (such as `\escapechar=-1 \let\#=#`) one can prepare either a bunch of macros (one (or even two) per character, such as `\expandafter\def\csname match#\endcsname #1\##{...}% last '#' is \catcode 13`) or a few macros with one `\def`ed as `\def\maintest #1<a list of all active characters and single letter cs's>{...}` doing all the heavy lifting (by recursively inserting the 'grabbed' token in the potential 'delimiter'). In between options (trading time for space) are also possible. As far as 'that is a lot of macros' it is a concern, of course. My (imperfect) take on this is: 'if one can afford that many `\catcode` registers, one can afford those special 'conditionals', as well).

I am afraid the *expansion propagation* problem mentioned above is simply the price of doing recursion in TeX. This problem can be somewhat mitigated by encoding (during the first pass) the tokens with `\yysx ?` where `\def\yysx#1#2{\expandafter\space\expandafter\yysx\expandafter#1\romannumeral-1#2}`. This way a `\romannumeral-1` in front of a list of `\yysx ?` entries will 'pass' the expansion to the end of the list while staying intact.

The 'brace post processing' feels like it *should* be avoidable.

Finally, I have got asked many times 'why no e-TeX?'. I am not sure this is a proper place to discuss it but I have (probably subjective) reasons to avoid it. If anyone can suggest a better place to discuss such preferences, I would appreciate it.

```
% helper macros (to build test cases, etc); @ is a letter

\def\yyreplacestring#1\in#2\with#3{%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\r@placestring\expandafter##\expandafter1\the#1##2\end{%
          \def\r@placestring{##2}% is this the string at the very end?
          \ifx\r@placestring\empty % then it is the one we inserted, report
              \errmessage{string <\the#1> not present in \the#2}% do not change the register if the string is not there
          \else % remove the extra copy of #1\end at the end
              \expandafter#2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                  {\expandafter\r@plac@string\expandafter{\the#3}{##1}##2\end}%
      \fi}% end of \r@placestring definition
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\r@plac@string
          \expandafter##\expandafter1%
          \expandafter##\expandafter2%
          \expandafter##\expandafter3%
          \the#1\end{##2##1##3}%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\r@placestring\expandafter\the\expandafter#2\the#1\end
}

\newtoks\toksa
\newtoks\toksb
\newtoks\toksc
\newtoks\toksd

\def\yybreak#1#2\yycontinue{\fi#1}

\def\eatone#1{}
\def\eatonespace#1 {}
\def\identity#1{#1}
\def\yyfirstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\yysecondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\yysecondofthree#1#2#3{#2}
\def\yythirdofthree#1#2#3{#3}

% #1 -- `call stack'
% #2 -- remaining sequence
% #3 -- `parsed' sequence

\def\yypreparsetokensequenc@#1#2#3{%
    \yystringempty{#2}{#1{#3}}{\yypreparsetokensequen@@{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\yypreparsetokensequen@@#1#2#3{% remaining sequence is nonempty
    \yystartsinbrace{#2}{\yydealwithbracedgroup{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\yypreparsetokensequ@n@@{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\yydealwithbracedgroup#1#2#3{% the first token of the remaining sequence is a brace
    \iffalse{\fi\yydealwithbracedgro@p#2}{#1}{#3}%
}

\def\yydealwithbracedgro@p#1{%
    \yypreparsetokensequenc@{\yyrepackagesequence}{#1}{}%
}

% #1 -- parsed sequence
% this is a sequence to `propagate expansion' into the next parameter.
% the same can be achieved by packaging the whole sequence with a 
% \csname ... \endcsname pair and using a simple \expandafter
% maybe that would be a better idea ...

\def\yyrepackagesequence#1{%
    \yyrepackagesequenc@{}#1\end
}

% #1 -- `packaged' sequence (\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter ? ...)
% #2 -- the next category 12 character or \end

\def\yyrepackagesequenc@#1#2{%
    \ifx#2\end
        \yybreak{\yyrepackagesequ@nc@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}}%
    \else
        \yybreak{\yyrepackagesequenc@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2}}%
    \yycontinue
}

% #1 -- `packaged' sequence (\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter ? ...)
% this macro is followed by the remainder of the original sequence with a so far
% unmatched right brace, the `call stack' and the parsed sequence.

\def\yyrepackagesequ@nc@#1{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\yyrepackagesequ@nc@swap#1{\expandafter\eatone\string}%
}

% #1 -- parsed sequence without packaging

\def\yyrepackagesequ@nc@swap#1#{%
    \yyrepackagesequ@nc@sw@p{#1}%
}

% #1 -- parsed `inner' sequence
% #2 -- remainder of the original sequence
% #3 -- `call stack'
% #4 -- parsed sequence so far

\def\yyrepackagesequ@nc@sw@p#1#2#3#4{%
    \yypreparsetokensequenc@{#3}{#2}{#4[#1]}%
}

% `braced group' thread ends here

% #1 -- `call stack'
% #2 -- remaining sequence
% #3 -- `parsed' sequence

\def\yypreparsetokensequ@n@@#1#2#3{% the remaining group in #2 is nonempty and does not start with a brace
    \yystartsinspace{#2}{\yyconsumetruespace{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\yypreparsetokenseq@@n@@{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\yyconsumetruespace#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\yyconsumetruespac@swap\expandafter{\eatonespace#2}{#1}{#3.}%
}

\def\yyconsumetruespac@swap#1#2#3{%
    \yypreparsetokensequenc@{#2}{#1}{#3}%
}

% `group starting with a true (character code 32, category code 10) space' thread ends here

% #1 -- `call stack'
% #2 -- remaining sequence
% #3 -- `parsed' sequence

\def\yypreparsetokenseq@@n@@#1#2#3{% a nonempty group, that does not start with a brace or a true space
    \yymatchblankspace{#2}{\yyrescanblankspace{#2}{#1}{#3}}{\yypreparsetokens@q@@n@@{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

% #1 -- remaining sequence
% #2 -- `call stack'
% #3 -- `parsed' sequence

\def\yyrescanblankspace#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \yyrescanblankspac@swap
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\yynormalizeblankspac@\meaning#1}{#2}{#3*}%
}

\def\yyrescanblankspac@swap#1#2#3{%
    \yystartsinspace{#1}{%
        \expandafter\yyrescanblankspac@sw@p\expandafter{\eatonespace#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
        \expandafter\yyrescanblankspac@sw@p\expandafter{\eatone#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}

\def\yyrescanblankspac@sw@p#1#2#3{%
    \yypreparsetokensequenc@{#2}{#1}{#3}%
}

% `group starting with a blank space' ends here

% #1 -- `call stack'
% #2 -- remaining sequence
% #3 -- `parsed' sequence

\def\yypreparsetokens@q@@n@@#1#2#3{% nonempty group starting with a non blank, non brace token
    \expandafter\yypreparsetokens@q@@n@@swap\expandafter{\eatone#2}{#1}{#30}%
}

\def\yypreparsetokens@q@@n@@swap#1#2#3{%
    \yypreparsetokensequenc@{#2}{#1}{#3}%
}

% #1 -- string of category code 12 or 10 characters
% #2 -- string of category code 12 or 10 characters

\def\yycomparesimplestrings#1#2{%
    \yystringempty{#1}{%
        \yystringempty{#2}{\yyfirstoftwo}{\yysecondoftwo}%
    }{\yycomparesimplestrings@{#1}{#2}}%
}

\def\yycomparesimplestrings@#1#2{% the first string is nonempty
    \yystringempty{#2}{\yysecondoftwo}{\yycomparesimplestrings@@{#1}{#2}}%
}

\def\yycomparesimplestrings@@#1#2{% both strings are nonempty
    \yystartsinspace{#1}{%
        \yystartsinspace{#2}{\yyabsorbfirstspace{#1}{#2}}{\yysecondoftwo}%
    }{%
        \yystartsinspace{#2}{\yysecondoftwo}{\yyabsorbfirstnonspace{#1}{#2}}%
    }    
}

\def\yyabsorbfirstspace#1#2{%
    \expandafter\yyabsorbfirstspac@swap\expandafter{\eatonespace#1}{#2}%
}

\def\yyabsorbfirstspac@swap#1#2{%
     \expandafter\yyabsorbfirst@swap\expandafter{\eatonespace#2}{#1}%
}

\def\yyabsorbfirstnonspace#1#2{%
    \expandafter\yyabsorbfirstnonspac@swap\expandafter{\eatone#1}{#2}%
}

\def\yyabsorbfirstnonspac@swap#1#2{%
     \expandafter\yyabsorbfirst@swap\expandafter{\eatone#2}{#1}%
}

\def\yyabsorbfirst@swap#1#2{%
     \yycomparesimplestrings{#2}{#1}%
}

% `compare strings of category code 12' thread ends here

% #1 -- remaining parsed sequence
% #2 -- analysed sequence

\def\yyanalysetokens@#1#2{%
    \yystringempty{#1}{{#2}}%
        {\yyanalysetok@ns@#1\end{#2}}%
}

\def\yyanalysetok@ns@#1#2\end{%
    \ifx#1.%
        \expandafter\yyfirstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\yysecondoftwo
    \fi
    {\yygrabablank{#2}}%
    {%
        \ifx#1[% not a space, an opening brace
            \expandafter\yyfirstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\yysecondoftwo
        \fi
        {%
            \yydisableobrace{#2}%
        }{% 
            \ifx#1]% not a space, a closing brace
                \expandafter\yyfirstoftwo
            \else
                \expandafter\yysecondoftwo
            \fi
            {%
                \yydisablecbrace{#2}%
            }{% neither space nor brace
                \yygrabtokenraw{#2}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

% #1 -- remaining parsed sequence
% #2 -- analysed sequence
% #3 -- next token

\def\yygrabtokenraw#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\yyanalysetokens@swap\expandafter{\meaning#3}{#1}{#2}%
}

\def\yyanalysetokens@swap#1#2#3{%
    \yyanalysetokens@{#2}{#3t#1e}%
}

\def\yygrabablank#1#2 {%
    \yyanalysetokens@{#1}{#2s0e}%
}

% #1 -- remaining parsed sequence
% #2 -- analysed sequence

\def\yydisablecbrace#1#2{%
    \yydisablecbrac@{}#1\relax#2\end
}


\def\yydisablecbrac@#1#2{%
    \ifx#2\end
        \yybreak{\yydisablecbrac@@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}}%
    \else
        \yybreak{\yydisablecbrac@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2}}%
    \yycontinue
}

\def\yydisablecbrac@@#1{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \yydisablecbrace@@@#1\end
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\iffalse}\fi\string
}

\def\yydisablecbrace@@@#1\relax#2\end#3{%
    \yystartsinspace{#3}%
        {\expandafter\yyanalysetok@nsswap\expandafter{\eatonespace#3}{#1}{#2c1e}}%
        {\expandafter\yyanalysetok@nsswap\expandafter{\eatone#3}{#1}{#2c2e}}%
}

\def\yyanalysetok@nsswap#1#2#3{%
    \iffalse{\fi\yyanalysetokens@{#2}{#3}#1}%
}

% #1 -- remaining parsed sequence
% #2 -- analysed sequence

\def\yydisableobrace#1#2{%
    \yydisableobrac@{}#1\relax#2\end
}


\def\yydisableobrac@#1#2{%
    \ifx#2\end
        \yybreak{\yydisableobrac@@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}}%
    \else
        \yybreak{\yydisableobrac@{#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2}}%
    \yycontinue
}

\def\yydisableobrac@@#1{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \yydisableobrace@@@#1\end
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\iffalse}\fi\string
}

\def\yydisableobrace@@@#1\relax#2\end#3{%
    \yystartsinspace{#3}%
        {\expandafter\yyanalysetok@nsswap\expandafter{\eatonespace#3}{#1}{#2o1e}}%
        {\expandafter\yyanalysetok@nsswap\expandafter{\eatone#3}{#1}{#2o2e}}%
}

\uccode`\ =`\-

% \dotspace expands into a character code `\-, category code 10 token (funny space)

\uppercase{\def\dotspace{ }}

\toksa\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\meaning\dotspace}

\toksb{-}

\toksc{#2}

\toksd\toksa

\yyreplacestring\toksb\in\toksa\with\toksc

\toksc{}
\yyreplacestring\toksb\in\toksd\with\toksc

\expandafter\def\expandafter\yymatchblankspac@\expandafter#\expandafter1\the\toksd{%
    \yystringempty{#1}{\expandafter\yysecondofthree\expandafter{\string}}%
        {\expandafter\yythirdofthree\expandafter{\string}}%
}

\edef\yymatchblankspace#1{% is it \catcode 10 token?
    \noexpand\iffalse{\noexpand\fi
    \noexpand\expandafter
    \noexpand\yymatchblankspac@
    \noexpand\meaning#1\the\toksd}%
}

% the idea behind the sequence below is that a leading character of category code 10
% is replaced either by a character of category code 10 and charachter code 32 or a character
% of category code 12 and character code other than 32
% note that while it is tempting to replace the definition below by something that ends in
% ... blank space #2{ ... with the hope of absorbing the result of \meaning in one step,
% this will not give the desired result in case of an active character,
% say, `~' that had been \let to the normal blank space

\expandafter\def\expandafter\yynormalizeblankspac@\expandafter#\expandafter1\the\toksd{}

\def\yystartsinspace#1{% is it \charcode 32, \catcode 10 token?
    \iffalse{\fi\yystartsinspac@#1 }%
}

\def\yystartsinspac@#1 {%
    \yystringempty{#1}{\expandafter\yysecondofthree\expandafter{\string}}{\expandafter\yythirdofthree\expandafter{\string}}%
}

\def\yystartsinbrace#1{%
  \iffalse{{\fi
  \if!\yytoks@mpty#1}}!%
    \expandafter\yysecondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\yyfirstoftwo
  \fi
}

\def\yystringempty#1{%
  \iffalse{{{\fi
  \ifcase\yytoks@mpty#1}}\@ne}\z@
    \expandafter\yyfirstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\yysecondoftwo
  \fi
}

\def\yytoks@mpty{%
    \expandafter\eatone\expandafter{\expandafter{%
        \ifcase\expandafter1\expandafter}\expandafter}\expandafter\fi\string
}

%% test code begins here

%\tracingmacros=3
%\tracingonline=3

\catcode`\ =13\relax%
\def\actspace{ }%
\catcode`\ =10\relax%

\catcode`\.=13\relax%
\def\actdotspace{.}%
\catcode`\.=12\relax%

\edef\makefunkydotspace{\let\expandafter\noexpand\actdotspace= \dotspace}
\edef\makefunkyspace{\let\expandafter\noexpand\actspace= \space}

\makefunkyspace
\makefunkydotspace

\catcode`\<=1
\catcode`\>=2
\uccode`\<=32
\uccode`\>=32

% inside the following sequence, < and > will become braces with character code 32 (space),
% \actspace will expand into an active character with character code 32, that has been \let to a
% character code 32, category code 10 token (space)

\uppercase{\edef\temptest{{ } \space\space\dotspace\expandafter\noexpand\actspace\expandafter\noexpand\actdotspace{<> {{}{{ u o l k kk
    \end\noexpand\fi\noexpand\else\noexpand\iffalse{}} }}}}}

%\uppercase{\edef\temptest{\dotspace E <>}}

\show\temptest

\def\displaypreparse#1{%
    \expandafter\errmessage\expandafter{\romannumeral-1\yypreparsetokensequenc@{\yyanalysetokens@}{#1}{}{}#1}%
}

\expandafter\displaypreparse\expandafter{\temptest}

\end
```

Comment: My apologies, I have omitted `\catcode\`\@=11` at the beginning in order not to mess up the 'backtics' (I do not remember if `\makeatletter` is available in plain TeX)